# Increase width of the map container size without moving the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a map view page in my project which contains google map.In my full view,  map container takes 70% (width) and  30% (width) of side container  which is the list view corresponding to the map markers.Side container having an  arrow button in the right corner, whenever I click on the button, side container should hide and  map container should show in the full view (from 70% to 100%) **without moving the map**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take three steps.

1. Resize the map container with JavaScript
2. Calculate the pixel offset of the map center and apply it to the map
3. Trigger the resize event to load tiles that were not displayed before

A working example follows (see it live on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkchs60d/)).

#### HTML

```
<div id="map"></div>
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

#### CSS

```
#map {
    width: 70%;
    height: ...
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
var state = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5167, 13.3833),
        zoom:   11
    });

    $('#toggle').click(function() {
        var width, offste;

        if ((state++ % 2) == 0) {
            width = 100;
            offset = $('#map').outerWidth() * (1.0 - 1.0 / 0.7) / 2.0 ;
        } else {
            width = 70;
            offset = $('#map').outerWidth() * (1.0 - 0.7) / 2.0 ;
        }

        $('#map').css('width', width + '%'); 
        map.panBy(offset, 0);
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });
});
```

Note that you may need to adapt the width and offset calculation to your particular case.